# MySQL Invalid Use of Group Function

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting `Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function` when trying to build a query in MySQL. Apparently MySQL doesn't support WITH, which is what I'm more comfortable using.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `UserID`
FROM `user`
INNER JOIN `message`
    ON `user`.`Message` = `message`.`Recipient`
WHERE MAX(`TotalSize`) IN (
                SELECT SUM(`message`.`Size`) as `TotalSize`
                FROM `message`
                INNER JOIN `category`
                    ON `message`.`CatID` = `category`.`CatID`
                WHERE `category`.`CatName` = 'Inbox'
                GROUP BY `Recipient`);
```

Comment: This query could be rewritten into an derived table approach.. share your table structures. with `show create table [table_name]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `UserID`, MAX(SUM(message.Size)) as TotalSize
FROM `user`
INNER JOIN `message`
    ON `user`.`Message` = `message`.`Recipient`
INNER JOIN category
    ON message.CatID = category.CatID
WHERE category.CatName = 'Inbox'
GROUP BY UserID
```

Comment: I am now getting an error that states Unknown column TotalSize in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'.

Comment: That means there isn't a `TotalSize` column in your tables. You need to compare the correct column with the result of your subquery.

Comment: It would help if you added your table schema to the question, and explained precisely what you're trying to do with the query.

Comment: I was doing SELECT SUM(`message`.`Size`) as TotalSize because I don't have a column in my table that already has the sum of sizes. I basically want to find the MAX SUM of sizes, grouped by UserID. I was thinking that by declaring SUM(`message.`Size`) as TotalSize, I could treat that as a column/list and then use that column/list in my outermost SELECT statement.

Comment: You can do that by joining with a subquery.

Comment: I've revised the query. But I'm not sure if it's correct, I don't know where `GROUP BY Recipient` would fit into this version. It would _really_ help if you posted your schema, some sample data, and the expected result. Making a sqlfiddle would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use HAVING clause instead of `WHERE MAX(`TotalSize`)`

```
SELECT DISTINCT `UserID`
FROM `user`
INNER JOIN `message`
    ON `user`.`Message` = `message`.`Recipient`
GROUP BY `UserID`
HAVING MAX(`message`.`Size`) IN (
                SELECT SUM(`message`.`Size`) as `TotalSize`
                FROM `message`
                INNER JOIN `category`
                    ON `message`.`CatID` = `category`.`CatID`
                WHERE `category`.`CatName` = 'Inbox'
                GROUP BY `Recipient`);
```

Group functions are not accessible in WHERE clause , `HAVING`  can filter on aggregates.

Comment: Any idea how to fix the `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column `TotalSize`in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'`?

Comment: @cdalto see my updated answer replace `TotalSize` with `message`.`Size` `HAVING MAX(message.Size) IN (...`